# Truth table boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

**I'm trying to make truth table for this and im terrible in boolean algebra. Can someone help me?**

(A'+B')C+ABC'+A'C

Comment: 'Help' is the right word, yes; we're not going to do this for you.  So, what do you have so far, and where are you getting stuck? Here's a question you should be able to answer: how many rows do you need?

Comment: I don't know how to start. Can you just make this example step by step and tell me what you did all steps?

Comment: OK, how about this: what columns will you have in the table?

Comment: ABC for sure others i don't know.

Comment: (A'+B')C  , ABC', A'C ?

Comment: Yes, those are all good!  OK, the three columns for just $A$, $B$, and $C$ are often called the 'reference columns'; they should reflect all the possible values that those three variables can take on. So, since each of those three can be either true (1) or false (0), how many possible combinations of values between those three variables can there be? (e.g. they can all be 1, or they can all be 0, or A and B can be 1 and C 0, or ..)

Comment: So i can make table with (A'+B')C | ABC' | A'C and just put 1, 0 in the right place and calculate?

Comment: Sure, that's the idea ... but the question is: how many and where exactly do you place those 1's and 0's?  To figure this out, the reference columns are key. So, with 3 variables A, B, and C, how many possible combinations of 0's and 1's do you have?

Comment: 8 combinations but if (A'+B')C giving result 2 (001) combination its just 1 yes?

Comment: Don;t think too far ahead ... yes, it's 8 combinations, so that's the way you set up the table. I'll show that in an Answer below now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up:

There are $3$ variables involved, $A$, $B$, and $C$. With $3$ variables, you get $2^3=8$ combination. You can get all those combinations systematically like this: 
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
A&B&C&statement(s) \ to \ be \ evaluated\\
\hline
0&0&0&\\
0&0&1&\\
0&1&0&\\
0&1&1&\\
1&0&0&\\
1&0&1&\\
1&1&0&\\
1&1&1&\\
\end{array}

See how I did that?  I had the $C$ alternate between $0$ and $1$ for every single row, the $B$ alternates every two rows, and the $A$ every four rows.

OK, rather than doing thew whole statement at once, break it down to its smaller terms. So, let's create a column for (A'+B')C, a column for ABC', and one for A'C:

\begin{array}{ccc|c|c|c}
A&B&C&(A'+B')C&ABC'&A'C\\
\hline
0&0&0&\\
0&0&1&\\
0&1&0&\\
0&1&1&\\
1&0&0&\\
1&0&1&\\
1&1&0&\\
1&1&1&\\
\end{array}

OK, the $ABC'$ is easy:

\begin{array}{ccc|c|c|c}
A&B&C&(A'+B')C&ABC'&A'C\\
\hline
0&0&0&&0\\
0&0&1&&0\\
0&1&0&&0\\
0&1&1&&0\\
1&0&0&&0\\
1&0&1&&0\\
1&1&0&&1\\
1&1&1&&0\\
\end{array}

OK, the $'C$ is pretty easy as well:

\begin{array}{ccc|c|c|c}
A&B&C&(A'+B')C&ABC'&A'C\\
\hline
0&0&0&&0&0\\
0&0&1&&0&1\\
0&1&0&&0&0\\
0&1&1&&0&1\\
1&0&0&&0&0\\
1&0&1&&0&0\\
1&1&0&&1&0\\
1&1&1&&0&0\\
\end{array}

Now, if the $(A'+B')C$ is too hard to do in $1$ step, we can just break that one down as well, i.e. let's first figure out ust the $A'+B'$ term:

\begin{array}{ccc|c|c|c|c}
A&B&C&A'+B'&(A'+B')C&ABC'&A'C\\
\hline
0&0&0&&&0&0\\
0&0&1&&&0&1\\
0&1&0&&&0&0\\
0&1&1&&&0&1\\
1&0&0&&&0&0\\
1&0&1&&&0&0\\
1&1&0&&&1&0\\
1&1&1&&&0&0\\
\end{array}

OK, $A'+B'$ is a $1$ as soon as either $A$ or $B$ is a $0$, so:

\begin{array}{ccc|c|c|c|c}
A&B&C&A'+B'&(A'+B')C&ABC'&A'C\\
\hline
0&0&0&1&&0&0\\
0&0&1&1&&0&1\\
0&1&0&1&&0&0\\
0&1&1&1&&0&1\\
1&0&0&1&&0&0\\
1&0&1&1&&0&0\\
1&1&0&0&&1&0\\
1&1&1&0&&0&0\\
\end{array}

And now let's 'multiply' that by $C$:

\begin{array}{ccc|c|c|c|c}
A&B&C&A'+B'&(A'+B')C&ABC'&A'C\\
\hline
0&0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&1&1&0&1\\
0&1&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&1&1&0&1\\
1&0&0&1&0&0&0\\
1&0&1&1&1&0&0\\
1&1&0&0&0&1&0\\
1&1&1&0&0&0&0\\
\end{array}

Finally, let's 'add' the three terms to get the truth-conditions of the statement as a whole:

\begin{array}{ccc|c|c|c|c|c}
A&B&C&A'+B'&(A'+B')C&ABC'&A'C&(A'+B')C+ABC'+A'C\\
\hline
0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&1&1&0&1&1\\
0&1&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&1&1&0&1&1\\
1&0&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
1&0&1&1&1&0&0&1\\
1&1&0&0&0&1&0&1\\
1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
\end{array}

Comment: Ok and how i can evaluate my statement now?

Comment: @MateuszZablocki Well, as you suggested yourself, rather than doing thew whole statement at once, break it down to its smaller terms. So, as you yourself already indicated, we can create a column for (A'+B')C, a column for ABC, and one for A'C. I'll add that to the table now ...  done ... now, I think the last two shouldn't be too hard: in fact, what should be the values in ABC from top to bottom?

Comment: There is ABC' not ABC. All expect (110) should be 0, yes?

Comment: @MateuszZablocki Whoops! Yes, it's ABC' rather than ABC, sorry about that!  And yes, you right, all except 110 are 0. OK, I'll fill that in. How about A'C?

Comment: 001, 011 give us result 1 others 0.

Comment: @MateuszZablocki Also correct! I'll fill those in too. Now, can you see the last one ... or is that one too hard to do in 1 step? If so, we can break it down further ....

Comment: 001,011,101,111 result is 1 others is 0. Am I right?

Comment: @MateuszZablocki Well, let me check ... I decided to add an extra step by first figuring out $A'+B'$ ... divide and conquer! :) OK,... adding those values now ...

Comment: @MateuszZablocki Well, I filled out the values, and yes, you get a 1 for 001,011, and 101, but a 0 for 111, because with 111 the A'+B' term is 0.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now i know better how to do it. :)

Comment: @MateuszZablocki Ypou're welcome!  Don;t forget to 'add' the three terms in the end. I'll do that too now and then I have to run ... Thanks for being responsive ... not everyone is like that :)